# MKV analytical tool to batch-process home movies library

Tags: windows, linux, video, statistics, mkv

I'd like to batch-process my home movies library (99% MKV files) and extract following data out of MKV metadata:

- List of all languages supported via subtitles for each image
- List of audio streams (languages)
- Number of channels per each audio stream
- Resolution and length

I am using Windows 11, but there should be no problem running a Linux software. I don't have access to any kind of Mac.

I can use a free software or it can be a paid one. Cloud is out of option, because I don't intend to upload 5 TB of data to any cloud service only to do some stats.

Comment: Something like this? https://mkvcleaver.informer.com/

Comment: If you can write an answer instead of comment and explain how can I use it in batch mode then I'll be happy to give you +25 credit for accepting such answer. I've read on the page you linked that it works for multiple-files, but form what I've learnt from first tutorial movie, it seems that it is 100% single file-oriented.